# Shiny + Google Analytics: my output table doesn't appear

Tags: r, windows, google-analytics, shiny

I try to pull data from Google Analytics with API-R. There are my two files for running my shiny app here:

**ui.R**

```
 shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

      headerPanel("My Shiny APP"),

      sidebarPanel( 
        dateRangeInput("dateRange",
                       label = "Select date range:",
                       start = Sys.Date() - 7, end = Sys.Date()-6)),

      mainPanel(

        fluidPage(
          fluidRow(
            column(12,
                   dataTableOutput("table")
            )
          )
        ))))
```

**server.R**

```
ga_token <- authorize(client.id = "XXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com", 
                      client.secret = "XXXXXXXXXXX",
                      cache = "token")

shinyServer(function(input, output){


  getDataFromGA <- reactive({

    ga.data <- get_ga(profileId = "ga:xxxxxxx", 
                              start.date =input$dateRange[1], end.date = input$dateRange[2], 
                              metrics = c("ga:sessions","ga:bounceRate"), dimensions = "ga:userType", 
                              samplingLevel = "HIGHER_PRECISION", start.index = NULL,
                              max.results = 10000, include.empty.rows = NULL, fetch.by = NULL, ga_token)

    return(ga.data)


  })

  output$table = renderDataTable({
    ga.data <- getDataFromGA()
    if (is.null(ga.data)) return(NULL)
    })
})
```

If I put a reactive expression at output$table, I have the same problem (**the output table doesn't appear**, and R doesn't print me any error message).
Libraries I load: devtools, RGA, shiny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of simply using reactive, you can try reactiveValues and observeEvent.
Your code may look something like:

```
    values <- reactiveValues(start.date = NULL, end.date = NULL, ga.data = NULL)

    observeEvent(input$dateRange, {
    values$start.date <- input$dateRange[1]
    values$end.date <- input$dateRange[2]
    values$ga.data <- get_ga(...) })
```

You can access the google analytics object as: values$ga.data

Comment: I try this, and I have found this message error: `Access token will be stored in the 'token' file.
Warning: Error in : is.atomic(x) is not TRUE
Stack trace (innermost first):
    70: stopifnot
    69: FUN
    68: vapply
    67: compact
    66: fix_query
    65: build_query
    64: get_ga
    63: observeEventHandler [C:\Users......]
     1: runApp
ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer`                                                 How to solve this?  is.atomic()? I don't understand why. Thanks Mohit Sainani

Comment: try including your ga_token object inside of the shinyServer function

Comment: your problem is in the renderDataTable. you should move the 'if' clause inside the reactive statement, make it return ga.data or NULL based on your logic, and only render 'getDataFromGA()' as it is